# How to show size of attached file in JTextField

Tags: java, netbeans

How can I show the size of the file I've selected from the JFileChooser in my JTextField? When I use `f.getTotalSpace()`, I'm being shown the total disk space of my PC, which is not what I want.

```
private void jButtonAttachActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    JFileChooser jc = new JFileChooser();
    jc.setDialogType(JFileChooser.OPEN_DIALOG);
    jc.showOpenDialog(null);
    File f = jc.getSelectedFile();

    if (f.length() / 1024 < 1024) {
        jTextFieldAttachments.setText(f.getName() + " " + "(" + f.length() / 1024 + " KB)");
    }
    else if (f.length() / 1024 >= 1024) {
        jTextFieldAttachments.setText(f.getName() + " " + "(" + f.length() / 1048576 + " MB)");
    }
}

**EDIT by @RoeyGolzarpoor**

        if (f.length() / 1024 <= 1024) {
            jTextFieldAttachments.setText(f.getName() + " " + "(" + String.format("%.1f", (f.length() / 1024)) + " KB)");
        }
        else if (f.length() / 1024 > 1024) {
            jTextFieldAttachments.setText(f.getName() + " " + "(" + String.format("%.1f", (f.length() / 1048576)) + " MB)");
        }
```

**Error**
[image: error]

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length%28%29

Comment: What unit of measurement does the number return? KB/MB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
float kilo_bytes f.length()/1024; 
Float.parseFloat(String.format("%.1f", kilo_bytes));
```

This will return your file in `KB`

Reminder:
1024 bytes = 1 Kilo Bytes  
1024 kb = 1 Mega Bytes 
1024 mb = 1 Gega Bytes 
1024 gb = 1 Tera Bytes

Comment: Cool. Is it possible to use an if statement to show the size in MB if the file is bigger than 1024 KB?

Comment: yes, as you probably know: 1024 kb = 1 Mega Bytes and so on

Comment: OK. So to show the size in MB do I use `f.length()*1024; `?

Comment: No, you need to use devision like I made in my answer, so the `.length()` is giving you the file in bytes

Comment: OK got it (`f.length()/1048576`). How can I show 1 demical place within the number?

Comment: You can also have a look at your file properties (alt+Enter) in Windows to see if your calculation are wrong or right. My promise, it will give you the same.

Comment: I think it's more to do with Javas inability to show numbers to 1 decimal place. Calculations are right but decimal vaules are not showing

Comment: Is Java even able to show numbers to 1 decimal place or more?

Comment: you can also mark that this answer helped you using the 'V'

Comment: Not sure how to use that in my 'else if' statement. Could you modify my else if statement as necessary please?

Comment: I was referring to the code for 1 decimal point in my file size number

Comment: Are you sure it's `l`?